# How to perform addition when number of arguments are dynamic in nature

Tags: java

I have following code. passing multiple arguments to public void add(int a,int ... b) method. in which i want to perform the addition.

```
public class emp {


    public void add(int a,int b){
        System.out.println("a+b--->"+(a+b));
    }

    public void add(int a,int b, int c){
        System.out.println("a+b+c---->"+(a+b+c));
    }

    public void add(int a,int ... b ){
        System.out.println("a+b+..."+(a+b));
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        emp e=new emp();
        e.add(12, 12);
        e.add(12,12,12,12,12);
    }
    }
```

How can i perform the addition when my number of arguments are dynamic?

Comment: If you use varargs (i.e. `...`) you get an array inside the method. You can iterate through the array.

Answer (score 3):

You can go over every element and add it. int... b is int[] b so use loop and add elements.
Something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
    // Do whatever you want here         
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use variable arguments.. something like this

```
public void add(int... b) {
    int result = 0;
    for(int a: b){
        result+=a;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers gave you an imperative solution through iteration. You can also implement this method in a functional way by using [`java.util.stream.IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html):

```
public int add(int a, int... b) {
    return IntStream.of(b).reduce(a, Integer::sum);
}
```